# Problemas al declarar funciones plantilla en C++

Tags: c++, lista, template, iteradores

Estaba trabajando en una función de ordenación para un proyecto. El tema es que me gustaría que funcionase para listas de cualquier tipo (imagino que hay librerías con métodos,tan solo quiero aprender a hacerlo por mi mismo), buscando encontré las template pero me han estado dando problemas.

```
template<typename T>
void merge(T ini_left, T final_left, T ini_right, T final right);
```

el problema aquí es que merge necesita hacer una lista auxiliar para ordenar los elementos, y no podía crear esta lista ya que T pretendía ser un iterador directamente.
Así llegué a la siguiente conclusion que me pareció mas acertada:

```
template <typename T>
void merge(list<T>::iterator ini_left,list<T>::iterator final_left,list<T>::iterator ini_right,list<T>::iterator final_right );
```

Permitiendome esto dentro de la funcion crear la lista auxiliar de la siguiente forma:

```
list<T> aux;
```

Pero he recibido el siguiente error al tratar de compilar mi programa de pruebas.
[image: Error terminal]

¿Que estoy entendiendo mal de los template?

Answer (score 2):

- ¿ Qué estoy entendiendo mal de los `template` ?

Tu problema es que `list< T >::iterator` es un [**tipo dependiente**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name). No existe por si mismo, sino que depende del argumento pasado a la plantilla `std::list< >`.

Para que ese código funcione, tienes que indicarle explícitamente al compilador ese hecho, que es un tipo dependiente:

```
template <typename T>
void merge( typename list<T>::iterator ini_left, typename list<T>::iterator final_left, typename list<T>::iterator ini_right, typename list<T>::iterator final_right ) {
    list< T > aux;
}
```

- Solución *a-lo-C++*

Para hacer lo que pretendes, existe la cabecera [`iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iterator). En ella se definen numerosos *rasgos* y herramientas para trabajar con este tipo de escenarios:

```
#include <list>
#include <iterator>

template< typename T >
void merge( T ini_left, T final_left, T ini_right, T final_right ) {
    using valueType = typename std::iterator_traits< T >::value_type;

    std::list< valueType > aux;
}
```

La *magia* está en `std::iterator_traits< >::value_type`. Ese tipo es aquél al que *apunta* el iterador usado.

Observa que, al igual que en tu problema inicial, es un **tipo dependiente**. Por ello el uso de `typename`.

Haciéndolo así, tu función queda incluso mas genérica: ahora puedes pasarle iteradores de cualquier tipo de contenedor, no solo de `list`.

Ten en cuenta que `iterator< >::value_type` solo está definida para los iteradores proporcionados por la propia librería estándar. Si intentas usarlo en iteradores creados por tí, tendrás que especializarla para que los soporte.

Comment: Muchas gracias! Me resolvió por completo el problema, era justo la informacion que necesitaba y no sabia encontrar por internet, leere mas sobre la palabra reservada "typename" para tratar de entender porque esto funciona. ahora he terminado con un error nuevo relacionado con los templates con el que me peleare unos dias mas antes de venir a preguntar por aquí. Una vez mas, muchas gracias por tu ayuda.